# Removing tool bar and figure title when using jupyter-matplotlib

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I'm using jupyter-matplotlib to embed charts as widgets in a jupyter widgets based dashboard.  However, I would like to disable the interactive tool bar and the figure title that automatically gets added.

As a simple example, the below creates an empty figure but it still has the interactive tool bar and Figure title.

```
%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

I would like to remove both the tool bar and figure title as well as anything else that is added padding around the plot, which I may not be able to see.

Comment: It looks like the ability to remove the title is a feature that is coming, see https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib/issues/134

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the latest jupyter-matplotlib version (0.5.3 as I am writting), you can use:

```
fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False
fig.canvas.header_visible = False
fig.canvas.footer_visible = False
```

You can also disable the resizing:

```
fig.canvas.resizable = False
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of `toolbar` you can use this

```
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
```

To remove title you can set the title to me empty something like this

```
fig.set_title("")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Unfortunately jupyter-matplotlib doesn't seem to follow the standard conventions.  I did figure out that fig.canvas.toolbar_visible = False can be used to turnoff the toolbar; I'm still working on the title.

Comment: `axes.get_figure().set_title("")` gets me `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_title'`